# Can I create pool of connection between SMSC and SMPP protocol for single port and split the load among?

Tags: java, sms, jsmpp, wso2-esb

I'm using JSMPP to crate the connection (binding) between SMSC(Service providers) and SMPP protocol. The current implementation is allow create a single connection.

But I want to create a pool of connection to a single SMSC port (Multiple binding) from WSO2 ESB and split the load among the binding. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is all ("Multiple binding", "split the load", "pool of connection") implemented in `"Apache Camel"` so you better look at it than reinvent it by yourself.

And also about multiple connection to SMSC on the same port and I suppose with the same account - you have to verify that this it is possible and allowed by SMSC and SMSC connection limits.